# how to display another html file in div

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have this javascript code and this html code below. What I want to do is when I select an option in the dropdown list, the index.html file on the subfolder will be displayed on the div.

```
<script>
 function display() {
var cake = document.getElementById("type").value;
document.getElementById("cakes").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" 
data="\'+cake+'\index.html" >   </object>';
}
</script>

<body>
<center><img src="LOGO.jpg" size=20%></img></center>
<p><center><font face="Brush Script MT" size="32" color="lightblue"`enter code here`>YOU'RE SO 
SWEETS</font></center></p>
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="home.png"></td>
<td><img src="product.png"></td>
<td><img src="online.png"></td>
<td><img src="about.png"></td>
<td><img src="contact.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<select id="type" multiple onchange="display()">
<option value="special">Specialty Cakes</option>
<option value="adult">Birthday Cakes for Adult</option>
<option value="kids">Birthday Cakes for Kids</option>
<option value="wedding">Wedding Cakes</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="cakes"></div>
```

Comment: Use `<iframe>` for this purpoeses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do the ugly way, you can use an iframe and change the src.

If you want to do the pretty way (which is kinda what most sites do nowadays), use Ajax to load the content into the div, specially because with Ajax the content will be **really** loaded into the div, while with iframe you will just open another HTML inside it, and if you eventually need to check stuff in/out of it, it will be a lot harder. Ajax would be my option (I never use iframe anyway)

If you don't know Ajax, I suggest either checking how prototypejs or jQuery implement it. It's easy and will give you better control over what you insert into the div.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Ajax to load content in the Div. You can learn about ajax from any good tutorial. A starting point may be -

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

**Update :**

From your Comment, my understanding is -

You can make use of jquery and use the variation of following snippet in your code from any function which will be triggered in onchange event of the select. you need to attach the jquery library.

```
$('#your-div-id').load('your-html-page.html');
```

Thanks.

Comment: looking only to use html and javascript codes for the site